# In Rational Developer for I Database perspective, change timestamp format

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400, ibm-rational

I'm used to working with timestamp format '2020-09-12-09.00.00.00000', for example.

I discovered, after a lot of trial and error, that I need to input '2020-09-12 09:00:00.000000' to achieve the same goal when using Rational Developer for i.  Is there a way to change that?

I don't need to do that when working directly on the emulator (using strsql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a JDBC thing. You need to change the driver property "timestamp format" to ibmsql vs. iso.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the message I got, it somehow started working again the next day.  I think the error was from the result and not from the querry.  I'll still mark your answer as the good one, cause I remember I once had to change that, too.  And it seems in line with the problem I was describing.